# How to deduce the Followers of non-terminals in syntax productions?

Tags: parsing, syntax, compiler-construction, grammar, production

Here is a set of Syntax Productions:

```
S -> SA | T
A -> +S | S | *
T -> (S) | a
```

when eliminate left recursion, I got these:

```
S -> TB
B -> AB | ε
A -> +S | TB | *
T -> (S) | a
```

and then I try to get the Firsts and Follows of the non-terminals in it following the steps the dragon book described. I have get Firsts correctly:

```
first(T) = [(, a]
first(A) = [+, *, (, a]
first(B) = [ε, +, *, (, a]
first(S) = [(, a]
```

But I can't figure out how get Follows. So can any one show how to do this specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the ***`FOLLOW(Non-Terminal)`***, apply the following rules until nothing can be added to the FOLLOW set : -        // Taken from Dragon Book

1. Place $ in FOLLOW(Start_Symbol),where $ is the input right endmarker.
2. If there is a production `A->XBY`, then everything in FIRST(Y) except ε is in FOLLOW(B).
3. If there is a production `A->XB`, or a production `A->XBY`, where FIRST(Y) contains ε,then everything in FOLLOW(A) is in FOLLOW(B).

So,now going as per the rules, we derive the FOLLOW() of all the non-terminals here .

***`FOLLOW(S) = {),$}`***  Since S is the start symbol, FOLLOW(S) must contain $.The production number 4th body (S) explains why the right parentheses is in FOLLOW(S).

***`FOLLOW(B) = {),$}`*** Since B appears only at the ends of bodies of S-productions(and not A-productions,discussed later in DISCUSSION Section).

***`FOLLOW(A) = {+,*,(,a,),$}`*** Since A appears in bodies only followed by B, thus,everything except ε that is in FIRST(B) must be in FOLLOW(A). However, since FIRST(B) contains ε, and B is derived from S in the initial production, hence, everything in FOLLOW(S) must also be in FOLLOW(A).That explains the symbols $ and ).

***`FOLLOW(T) = {+,*,(,a,),$}`*** Since T appears in bodies only followed by B, thus,everything except ε that is in FIRST(B) must be in FOLLOW(T). However, since FIRST(B) contains ε,and B is the entire-string following T in the bodies of the S productions,everything in FOLLOW(S) must also be in FOLLOW(T).That explains the symbols $ and ).

**DISCUSSION :-**

Now,talking about some kind of conflict arising because of 3rd production,**`A -> +S | TB | *`**, you could've easily substituted S in place of TB, because of which you may be confused.

As per me, you should leave the productions as :-

```
S -> TB
B -> AB | ε
A -> +S | S | *  //substitute S for understanding FOLLOW(B) without any confusion
T -> (S) | a
```

Comment: This question is the exercise 4.4.1 d) of the dragon book. But actually I haven't get official answer of this book. The only answer I can find is here [link](https://github.com/fool2fish/dragon-book-exercise-answers/blob/master/ch04%2F4.4%2F4.4.md) . This answer is pretty weird. Could you explain it?

Comment: @EricHuang- I also think that answer is muddled in itself. Can't say for sure,but, there seems some mistake. If you could verify from your Professor,it would be so grateful of you.